# RSpec and protected methods, controller spec for current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I might be going at this the wrong way. I'm doing the spec first, BDD/TDD and hit a bump.

I have this application_controller_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicationController do
  describe "current_user" do
    it "should return nil if no one is logged in" do
      subject.current_user.should be_nil
    end
    it "should return currently logged in user" do
      hash = {user_id: "my_id"}
      subject.should_receive(:session).and_return hash
      subject.current_user.should == "my_id"
    end
  end
end
```

which works perfectly fine ***without*** the `protected` keyword.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_user

  protected
  def current_user
    session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

***with*** the `protected` enabled, I get this error msg

```
NoMethodError: protected method `current_user' called for #<ApplicationController:0x2a90888>
```

I should be able to test using the helper_method... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`helper_method` makes the method available in the views, not the controller, according to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/TestCase/Behavior/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method).

If you really need to access the method from controller specs, you could use `send`:

```
subject.send(:current_user).should be_nil
```

But you might want to consider whether testing non-public methods makes sense, or if it would be better to test using view specs. Or whether the method needs to be protected in the first place. It might also be instructive to see how Devise and Authlogic implement testing for their `current_user` methods.

Comment: It's a special case, it's part of public api, through `helper_method`, so it should be spec'd in isolation, but as its marked as protected (seems to be a well-established pattern for `current_user`) it makes writing the spec harder... I'll research devise source. thx!

Comment: devise generates current_user, as `def current_#{mapping}`. `lib/devise/controllers/helper.rb#self.define_helpers`. No isolated tests, just through helpers and `assigns(:current_user)`. Difficult to browse such generic code. I'd like to be able to access the helper_method as it's part of public api.

Comment: To add some clarify - the reason `send` is needed here isn't due to anything with `helper_method`, it's simply because the method is protected.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's been quite some time since the original question, maybe someone finds this useful.

You can make an anonymous subclass of the `ApplicationController` and expose protected methods inside it. No need for `send()` method.

Here is how to do it:

```
describe ApplicationController, type: :controller do
  controller do
    def current_user
      super
    end
  end

  ...

  it 'should return nil if no one is logged in' do
    expect(controller.current_user).to be_nil # (or whatever)
  end

end
```

The source is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658312) SO answer.