# testing a redirect in rspec and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

i want to to write a controler test to check that on a successful sign in, a user is redirected to a certain page. the current test I have at the moment is returning a 200.

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Admin::EntriesController, :type => :controller do

setup_factories
    describe "after login" do 
        it "should redirect to pending after logged in" do
            sign_in admin
        expect(response).to redirect_to('admin/entries/pending') 
        end
    end

end
```

which returns

```
   Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to('admin/entries/pending')
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

the relevant controller

```
class AdminController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  protected 

  def after_sign_in_path_for(admin)
    pending_admin_entries_path
  end

end
```

am I attempting this is in the right way, where am i going wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sign_in` user in RSpec doesn't make a request so you cannot test the redirection.

For `after_sign_in_path`, you can test like this:

```
it 'redirects user to pending admin entries path' do    
  expect(controller.after_sign_in_path(user)).to eq pending_admin_entries_path
end
```

Comment: This may not work as `after_sign_in_path` is a protected method. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658251/how-to-test-after-sign-in-path-forresource for a more complete answer.