# Rspec - How to test ApplicationController login redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My login redirects a user to the page they intended to view, and I want to write a test for this.  I have a function that redirects the user after login if a `session[:previous_url]` variable is set.

**The method I'm trying to test**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if request.referer == new_user_session_url
    super
  else
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
end
```

**The test I have so far**

```
describe ApplicationController do
  describe "login should redirect to intended page" do
    it "should redirect to policies page on login" do
      session[:previous_url] = '/page'
      @customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user,:customer => @customer)
      sign_in @user
      expect(response).to redirect_to("/page")
    end
  end
end
```

**This gives me the following error**

> Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to("/policies") Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>.

Comment: What is `sign_in` in `sign_in @user`? Is this actually a HTTP request? or is this method just setting up the session to be `@user`? If you are using `devise`, then `sign_in @user` is not a HTTP request, in which then your controller spec will not work, because essentially your `after_sign_in_path_for` callback will never be called.

Comment: I am using devise. Is there any way to test this method?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658251/how-to-test-after-sign-in-path-forresource