# How to test after_sign_in_path_for by minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, minitest

I changed the default behavior of `after_sign_in_path_for` method like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    return admin_root_path if resource.is_a?(AdminUser)
    request.referrer || root_path
  end
end
```

It works find and now I want to test it by `minitest`.
But I couldn't figure out how to write integration test for it.

Although there is an answer for `rspec`, I couln't rewrite for `minitest`.

[How to test after_sign_in_path_for(resource)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658251/how-to-test-after-sign-in-path-forresource)

How can I write the test for `after_sign_in_path_for` by `minitest`?

Rails: 5.1
devise: 4.5.0

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  setup do
    2.times{ create(:post) }
    @user = create(:user)
    @admin_user = create(:admin_user)
  end

  test "should redirect to '/posts/1' after login" do
    # get "/posts/1"
    # sign_in(@user)
    # test return back "/posts/1"
  end

  test "should redirect to '/posts/2' after login" do
    # get "/posts/2"
    # sign_in(@user)
    # test return back "/posts/2"
  end

  test "should redirect to admin root page after login" do
    # sign_in(@adminuser)
    # test go to admin root page
  end
end
```

Comment: The generally accepted trend is to move away from Controller tests and use System tests instead. So, create the appropriate user account, sign in and check which page you land on. Repeat for admin.

Comment: Can you show me an example or a document page for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can test them like so:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  setup do
    @user = create(:user)
    @admin_user = create(:admin_user)
  end

  test "should redirect to current page after login" do
    sign_in(@user)
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to controller: "home", action: "index"
  end

  test "should redirect to admin root page after login" do
    sign_in(@adminuser)
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to controller: "admin", action: "index"
  end
end
```

[assert_redirected_to API docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions/assert_redirected_to)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to write a test for a redirection when `sign_in`, while your example shows how to test redirection according to sign-in status.

Comment: Doesn't `sign_in` status change where a user is redirected? You have to know if they are admin or regular user to test where they will be redirected, right?

Comment: Kinda yes, but not when the `get` method is called, but when `after_sign_in_path_for` is called. Maybe my example code was not clear. I changed it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, your example was a little misleading. So, you want to make sure that they return to the correct path after the successful sign in. No matter what path (for regular users). Well, actually, in my opinion testing two paths + the admin path in your edited example is a decent solution. It proves that a user, when signed in, is redirected to the previous path. I might place two different sign in attempts and redirects in a single method so it's clear that I'm testing that function specifically. But it works, right?